# Deploy a Visual Studio application in a recently installed emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2008, emulation, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm trying to deploy an Visual Studio 2008 application in an emulator. I've downloaded the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK from this [page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389), which comes with some emulators.
The Emulator Manager from Visual Studio recognize them, but not at the moment of the deploy an application, when I try to deploy mi solution it appears a pop-up with the different versions of emulators, but the ones from 6.5.3 DTK don't appear to select. How can I configure Visual Studio to be able to select this new installed emulators?

Comment: Possibly your "Target Platform" does not match the WM653pro emulator image (for example you have target=Windows Mobile 5 SDK). Check your deploy settings and/or the solution configuration manager. You can also start and then Cradle the Emulator Image in Device Emu Manager and then just use the "... Device" instead of an emulator. Then VS will use the ActiveSynced device for deploy and debug.

Comment: Anyone has an answer for this?

Comment: @igarcia can you accept the answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project ->right click -> change target platform

[image: Changing target platform in Visual studio]

Select the appropriate platform from the drop down

[image: Choose target platform]

Run the application and select the environment to deploy
[image]