# Mobile 6.5.3 TDK platform not listed for selection

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, emulation

I have the same issue as [Deploy a Visual Studio application in a recently installed emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200383/deploy-a-visual-studio-application-in-a-recently-installed-emulator/19031675#19031675) but when I select "Change platform" the desired platform is not listed.  It lists only "Pocket PC 2003", "Windows CE 5.0", "Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK", and "Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK" (currently selected).  "Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK" is not listed but the 6.5.3 TDK is definitely installed on my system.  I confirmed the emulator images in the ~\Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK\PocketPC\Deviceemulation\0409 folder just like those found for the 6.0 SDK in ~\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\PocketPC\Deviceemulation\0409.

The "Device Emulator Manager" knows about them and from VS2005 I can select "Tools -> Connect to Device" and connect to a 6.5.3 emulator.  But there is no ability to select them for a project/solution.

Maybe a missing registry entry?